# Running Java Swing GUI application on Docker

Tags: java, swing, docker, dockerfile, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to run a custom java swing GUI using the docker toolbox in windows.
I want to now containerize this application however getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
/opt/jdk1.8.0_202/jre
/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

I am running a dockerfile.
The setup is:

> 1) Install Linux
>
> 2) Install JDK
>
> 3) Copy over the folder containing
>   the JAR
>
> 4) run the docker container which would bring up the GUI ( not
>   the linux front-end , not using a vnc is preferred).

I am using *Xlaunch* for the terminal on windows and am able to launch a firefox on docker using this.

## This is the first docker file

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java
COPY ./myJarFolder /home/myJarFolder
CMD ["java","-jar","/home/myJarFolder/myJarFile.jar"]
```

## This is the second docker file

```
FROM alpine:3.2

MAINTAINER Anastas Dancha [...]

# Install cURL

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

# Java Version

ENV JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR 8

ENV JAVA_VERSION_MINOR 45

ENV JAVA_VERSION_BUILD 14

ENV JAVA_PACKAGE       jdk

# Download and unarchive Java

RUN mkdir /opt && / curl -jksSLH "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" && / http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-b${JAVA_VERSION_BUILD}/${JAVA_PACKAGE}-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar -xzf - -C /opt && / ln -s /opt/jdk1.${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}.0_${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR} /opt/jdk && / rm -rf /opt/jdk/*src.zip && /opt/jdk/lib/missioncontrol && /opt/jdk/lib/visualvm && /opt/jdk/lib/*javafx* && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar && /opt/jdk/jre/bin/javaws && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/desktop && /opt/jdk/jre/plugin && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/deploy* && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/*javafx* && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/*jfx* && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libdecora_sse.so && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_*.so && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfxplugins.so && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libglass.so && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libgstreamer-lite.so && /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx*.so &&    /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjfx*.so

# Set environment

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk

ENV PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin   

# COPY myJarFolder from local repository to the image

COPY ./myJarFolder /usr/local/myJarFolder 

# Start the image with the jar file as the entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "usr/local/myJarFolder/myJarFile.jar"]

# EOF
```

## I am getting this error with the first dockerfile

> $ docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=10.193.146.124:0.0 myDocker:1.0
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /opt/jdk1.8.0_202/jre /lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such  file or directory
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
>           at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
>           at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
>           at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
>           at java.awt.Toolkit.(Toolkit.java:1670)
>           at java.awt.Component.(Component.java:593)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
>   der.java:56)

I am getting *permission error* with the **second dockerfile** at *mkdir /opt* line.

Can someone please let me know the correct way of doing it in windows.

Comment: You will find it vastly easier to just install a JVM on your host and run the jar file there.  To make this work you also need an X server on your Windows host system and deal with X forwarding and permissions issues between the Docker Toolbox VM, the container, and the host; and this is _after_ you get the correct library stack in your image.  From everything I’ve seen Docker just isn’t a good way to run interactive desktop applications.

Comment: A couple of other comments: 1. You're using Alpine 3.2 - that's ancient. 2. More importantly, the error message suggest Java fails to load a native library - this could mean deep libc incompatibility (Alpine is based on musl libc, rather than the more common glibc). Consider trying with `ubuntu:18.04`.

Comment: @valiano Tried with latest Alpine still no luck.

Comment: @David Maze Tried with Ubuntu but got some permission error while using either curl or mkdir

Comment: Same problem with Alpine 3.17.0

Answer (score 2):

Did some more research and by hit and trial following code seems to launch the GUI ,there are some errors after that but that must be due to some other issues in the GUI itself:

```
FROM openjdk:8

# Set environment

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk

ENV PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin   

# COPY myJarFolder from local repository to the image

COPY ./myJarFolder /usr/local/myJarFolder

# Start the image with the jar file as the entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/local/myJarFolder/myJarFile.jar"]

# EOF
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please include this information inside your question.

Comment: @Deep Glad you got it working. `openjdk:8` is based on Debian stretch - that's probably a better fit than Alpine for this use case, since it is glibc based.

Comment: @emix : I believe it is , since the question was to run a custom jar using dockerfile.The problem I faced was due to the tool I was using ( Alpine Linux here), now I have changed the tool (openJDK) but the question remained the same and it got resolved by doing so. If you still think otherwise let me know and I will be happy to include it in the question.